# If contains, countifs?

Tags: google-sheets

[image]

Is there a formula which would allow me to automatically put the answer in the place where it says *answer here * ? For example it analyzes column 2 to see where the Y which would be row 2 and thus the answer is row 2 column 1.

Answer (score 0):

Making some obvious assumptions about the screenshot in the question:

```
=filter(A2:A4, B2:B4="Y")
```